# How to detect if a function exists?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to detect if a specific overload for my function is callable. I assumed I could do something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence), but I believe the issue is that the function signature `template<typename From, typename To> convert(const From&)` is well defined, but the instantiation is not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename From, typename To>
To convert(const From& from)
{
    // I have a lot of additional template specializations for this function
    return from; 
}

template<typename From, typename To>
struct IsConvertible
{
    template<typename = decltype(convert<From, To>(From()))>
    static std::true_type test(int);
    template<typename T>
    static std::false_type test(...);

    static bool const value = decltype(test(0))::value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "IsConvertible=" << IsConvertible<int, float>::value << std::endl;
    // Returns 1 as expected

    std::cout << "IsConvertible=" << IsConvertible<int, std::string>::value << std::endl;
    // Returns 1, expected 0. The issue seems to be that decltype(convert<From, To>(From()))
    // is somehow ok, although convert<int, std::string>(1) definitly isn't
}
```

I want to use `IsConvertible` for some additional metaprogramming. **Is it possible to detect if the `template<typename From, typename To> To convert(const From&)` function is actually callable?`**

Comment: No. This is called SFINAE unfriendly.

Comment: My 2 cents: I tried on coliru because I struggled to believe... [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15ef837e704941a3).

Comment: This already exists: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible

Comment: It's not an overload, it's a specialisation. You can detect if an overload exists, but you cannot detect if a specialisation exists. Use overloads.

Comment: Googling for "SFINAE unfriendly" I found this: [SFINAE-friendly std::bind](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0826r0.html)

Comment: @chris Note that I have many specializations for the `convert<From, To>` function for types which does not have a trivial conversion operation, i.e. checking for `std::is_convertible` is not sufficient.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry I'm not sure I understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm not sure what's to elaborate. Do not use template specialisations for conversion, use overloads. The slight problem is that you cannot overload on return type, but this is easily fixable with a tag type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With declaration of

```
template<typename From, typename To> To convert(const From& from);
```

Your traits

```
template<typename From, typename To>
struct IsConvertible
```

would always detect presence of `convert` function.

One way to fix it is overloads and/or SFINAE:

```
template <typename> struct Tag{};

int convertImpl(tag<int>, const std::string& from);
float convertImpl(tag<float>, const std::string& from);
// overloads ...

template<typename From, typename To>
auto convert(const From& from)
-> decltype(convertImpl(tag<To>{}, from))
{
    return convertImpl(tag<To>{}, from);
}
```

Comment: Ah of course -- this makes a lot of sense. Now I understand n.m.'s as well!

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood your question but is not the using `std::is_invocable` enough in this case as showcased in the following?

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename From, typename To>
To convert(const From& from)
{
    // I have a lot of additional template specializations for this function
    return from; 
}

template<>
std::string convert(const int& from)
{
    //silly specialization
    return "2"+from; 
}


struct Foo{
    int bar;
};

int main()
{
   //ok specialization is called 
   std::cout<<std::is_invocable<decltype(convert<int,std::string>),std::string>::value<<std::endl; 
   //no way I can convert int to Foo, specialization required
   std::cout<<std::is_invocable<decltype(convert<int,Foo>),Foo>::value<<std::endl; 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged C++11.

Comment: I didn't know about std::invocable, so +1 for that. But as the previous commenter indeed said, I'm unfortunately stuck with C++11.

Comment: @pingul what you might want to do is to look into how `invocable` is implemented and see if you can do something similar. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems in your code.

Without a particular order...

(1) SFINAE, using `decltype()`, check only the presence of a **declared** function; doesn't check if that function is defined or if it's definition works (compile) or not.

I propose you to rewrite `convert()` using directly SFINAE to **declare** it only when is compilable

```
template <typename To, typename From,
          decltype( To(std::declval<From>()), bool{} ) = true>
To convert (From const & f)
 { return f; }
```

This way `convert()` is declared only if you can construct a `To` object starting from a `From` object.

(2) Observe that I've also switched the order of `To` and `From`: this way you can call the `convert()` function explicating only the `To` type

```
convert<float>(0); // From is deduced as int from the 0 value
```

If you declare `To` (that isn't deducible) after `From` (that is deducible), you necessarily have to explicit both types, calling the function, also when the `From` type is deducible.

(3) Your `IsConvertible` struct doesn't works.

It's a common error using SFINAE.

When you write

```
template<typename = decltype(convert<From, To>(From()))>
static std::true_type test(int);
```

you're trying enable/disable this `test()` method using SFINAE over `From` and `To` that are the template parameters of the **struct**

Wrong.

SFINAE works over template parameters of the method itself.

If you want to use SFINAE, you have to transform `From` and `To` in template parameters of the method; by example

```
template <typename F = From, typename T = To,
          typename = decltype(convert<F, T>(std::declval<F>()))>
static std::true_type test(int);
```

Now SFINAE uses `F` and `T` that are template parameters of the `test()` method and this is correct.

(4) Observe that I've written `std::declval<F>()` instead of `F()`. It's because you're not sure that `F` (`From`) is default constructible. With `std::declval()` you go around this problem.

I propose a different `IsConvertible` custom type traits that take in count the `From`/`To` inversion and demand to the `value` call of `test()` the `From`+`To`->`F`+`T` type conversion

```
template <typename To, typename From>
struct IsConvertible
 {
   template <typename T, typename F,
             typename = decltype(convert<T>(std::declval<F>()))>
   static std::true_type test(int);

   template <typename...>
   static std::false_type test(...);

   static bool const value = decltype(test<To, From>(0))::value;
 };
```

(5) you're expecting that

```
IsConvertible<int, std::string>::value
```

is zero; but you forgetting that `std::string` is constructible from `int`; so this value (or `IsConvertible<std::string, int>`, switching `To` and `From`) should be one.

The following is a corrected full working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename To, typename From,
          decltype( To(std::declval<From>()), bool{} ) = true>
To convert (From const & f)
 { return f; }

template <typename To, typename From>
struct IsConvertible
 {
   template <typename T, typename F,
             typename = decltype(convert<T>(std::declval<F>()))>
   static std::true_type test(int);

   template <typename...>
   static std::false_type test(...);

   static bool const value = decltype(test<To, From>(0))::value;
 };

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << "IsConvertible=" << IsConvertible<float, int>::value
      << std::endl;

   std::cout << "IsConvertible=" << IsConvertible<int, std::string>::value
      << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: The missing thing in this example is that my `convert` function has many specializations/overloads for non-trivially convertible types, and so adding in `decltype( To(std::declval<From>()), bool{} ) = true>` as a condition will not work. However, your #3 and #4 are correct and I've used it together with the answer from Jarod. Much appreciated!